# How can I upload a file using put method and post the other form variables in one single form?

Tags: php, post, file-upload, put

If I use post method for all with one submit click I can upload files and other variables. I want to try using put method and also want to send post variables with the file in one form and one submit click.

Comment: "I want to try using put method" You mean [this](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.put-method.php)?

Comment: A HTTP request can either be `PUT` or `POST`. You can't use both methods at the same time. So the question is, why would you want it anyway?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that's the normal operating method for forms. There's nothing special about a file upload form, except having to specify the `enctype`. You can have other fields in the same form and they'll all be sent together when the Submit button is pressed.

The only server-side difference in PHP is that file upload data is in the $_FILES superglobal. Other fields will be in $_POST as usual.